# Azure File Copy failing on second run in build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I am using the "Azure File Copy" task in Azure Devops, which as far as I can see, uses an Az copy command to copy a file into Azure storage.

Here's my task definition for this:

[image]

*[Note - this is v3 of the task]*

This works fine on first run of the task within a build pipeline, and creates the file in the container as expected (shown below):

[image]

When I run the task in the pipeline subsequent times, it fails.  I can see from the error it seems to be prompting for overwrite options - Yes/No/All.  See below:

[image]

**My Question:**
Does anyone know how I give the task arguments that will tell it to force overwrite each time?  Documentation for this on the Microsoft website isn't great and I can't find an example on the Github repo.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Full Error:

```
    & "AzCopy\AzCopy.exe" /Source:"D:\a\1\s\TestResults\Coverage\Reports" /Dest:"https://project1.blob.core.windows.net/examplecontainer" /@:"D:\a\_temp\36c17ff3-27da-46a2-95d7-7f3a01eab368" /SetContentType:image/png /Pattern:"Example.png"
[2020/04/18 21:29:18][ERROR] D:\a\1\s\TestResults\Coverage\Reports\Example.png: No input is received when user needed to make a choice among several given options.
Overwrite https://project1.blob.core.windows.net/examplecontainer/Example.png with D:\a\1\s\TestResults\Coverage\Reports\Example.png? (Yes/No/All) [2020/04/18 21:29:18] Transfer summary:
-----------------
Total files transferred: 1
Transfer successfully:   0
Transfer skipped:        0
Transfer failed:         1
Elapsed time:            00.00:00:01
##[error]Upload to container: 'examplecontainer' in storage account: 'project1' with blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.' For more info please refer to https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme
```

Comment: NOTE - I fixed this by using version 1 of the task - couldn't figure out what version 3 was looking for.  Working for me now using v1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so much as solution, as a workaround but I set this to version 1 of the task and it worked for me!

Comment: Although this doesn't exactly answer why the error happened, switching the Task version to the previous version, fixed the issue :)

Comment: Version 4.* is now out... the solution cannot be to go the whole way back to v1!

Comment: It was noted as a workaround at the time.  Feel free to add an updated answer and I can change mark it as correct for sure! :)